# Uses of Ramsey Theory in Astronomy?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, ramsey-theory

In the last paragraph of a Scientific American article of July 1990 that can be found here

http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~ronspubs/90_06_ramsey_theory.pdf

Graham and Spencer write

"Today we can easily recognize the constellations in the night sky as a consequence of Ramsey theory."

Really? What exactly is done and how? Please could someone provide some details and/or references.

Comment: The quote make more sense when you add what comes before it: "Yet most stargazers would agree that the night sky appears to be filled with constellations in the shape of straight lines and pentagons. Could it be that such geometrical patters arise from unknown forces in the cosmos? Mathematics provides a much more plausible explanation."

Comment: Still, "as a consequence of" seems a strong choice of words... maybe there really is something that we can do just because of RT?

Comment: It's just a popular article that is trying to explain Ramsey theory in a low-level language don't read it too literally.

Comment: Definitely, but is the claim, as stated above, true or false?

Comment: It's not false.

Comment: I am jealous of your obviously extensive collection of old Scientific American issues.

Answer (score 6):

I wouldn't take the comment too seriously, but I think it's just saying that for a large and quasi-random set of 3D points (stars), there is a 2D projection (our perspective of them), which contains subsets of stars that form different patterns (constellations).  It's a bit of a stretch to say that this is Ramsey theory (because constellations aren't really straight lines or any consistent geometric shape, and it's not clear what is being proved here (eg is it any 2D projections that would do this)) - I would say this is more of an indication of evolution to create over-active pattern recognition in humans!